# Remove div after append and changing div

Tags: javascript, jquery

So basically I have this form where I want the user to be able to add another field to the form and also expand fields getting more options.

To easily try out the code here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LH8sd/6/

Currently nothing works, what I need to get working is the ability to click the arrow so the other options for the field appears and also the ability to remove a row.

If you are going to check out the JSFiddle, for some reason it does not work if I don't externally include my JS-file so you can check out the about_settings.js to look for error as well.

This is my JS-code that is associated with what I want:

```
var count = 1;

function addRow() {
    if (count < 5) {
        $('#Rows').append('<div id="form-' + count + '"><a href="#"><div class="workedu_right" id="workedu_right_' + count + '" onclick="workEduShow();"></div></a><input type="text" name="workedu" placeholder="School name or work name " /> <ul class="workedu_buttons"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><li class="workedu_minus" onclick="removeRow();"></li></a><a href="javascript:void(0);"><li class="workedu_plus" onclick="addRow();"></li></a></ul><div class="global_hide" id="workedu_hide_' + count + '"><input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title etc. Engineer, Student" /><br /></div></div>');
        count++;
    } else {
        alert("Limit reached!");
    }
}

function removeRow() {
    $newEl.on("click", function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    count--;
}

function workEduShow() {
    $('#workedu_right_' + count).toggleClass("workedu_down");
    $('#workedu_hide_' + count).slideToggle(250);
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I get 1000 errors per second in that fiddle without touching anything (Chrome). Sizzle in  file `jquery-latest.js` is getting mad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While appending a new row, pass the `count` value through `removeRow` function, In that way you will be able to remove the unique rows.

```
// pass count value while appending

<li class="workedu_minus" onclick="removeRow('+count+');"></li> 


function removeRow(ele) {

$("#form-"+ele).remove(); // remove the specific div 
count--;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LH8sd/7/)

Answer (score 0):

try sending the `count` value to the functions as arguments
 and remove only divs based on it.

updated the fiddle according to your requirements.plz have a look
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LH8sd/10/)

Answer (score -1):

I think $newEl does not have reference to newly created element. try

```
function removeRow(newEl) {
    $(newEl).on("click", function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    count--;
}
```